# chrome.storage saving values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I'm trying to make a chrome extension to store stuff like "Name " and to list them as buttons so I can share current page to anyone from the list. Right now, I'm trying to write/read from chrome.storage (cloud) but my JS isn't really doing anything! The code seems fine, it just doesn't do anything!

```
window.load = myJs;

function myJs() {

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var link = document.getElementById('get');
        link.addEventListener('click', function () {
            function getValues() {
                chrome.storage.local.get('Name', function (result) {
                    Name = result;
                    alert(result);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var link = document.getElementById('savechanges');
        link.addEventListener('click', function () {
            function saveChanges() {
                var newname = getElementById("newname");
                var newemail = getElementById("newmail");
                if (!newname) {
                    message('Error: No name specified');
                    return;
                }
                if (!newemail) {
                    message('Error: No E-mail specified');
                    return;
                }
                chrome.storage.sync.set({
                    'Name': newname
                }, {
                    'Email': newemail
                }, function () {
                    message('New contact added');
                    window.location.href = "popup.html";
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

So my extension has 2 pages, one for adding new people with 2 inputs, and one for grabing the values (at least for now, I plan on listing them as button as soon as I find out how)

Here is the html from both

```
page.html

 <body>
   <input type="text" id="newname" placeholder="Enter new contact name">
    <input type="text" id="newemail" placeholder="Enter new contact email">
    <button name="Add" id="savechanges" class="m-btn">Add new contact</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>

popup.html

 <body>
   <button type="button" id="get" class="m-btn">Get</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <a href="page.html"><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" class="m-btn"></a>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, your event listeners are declaring two local functions, `getValues` and `saveChanges`, that are never called.  You can just remove these outer function declarations and let the body of these two functions be the body of the event handlers, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var link = document.getElementById('get');
  link.addEventListener('click', function () {
    chrome.storage.local.get('Name', function (result) {
      // Check chrome.runtime.lastError to see if there was an error
      Name = result;
      alert(result);
    });
  });
});
```

You should be able to inspect your popup / background pages to debug your scripts in the Sources tab in Chrome's developer tools.  I would set some breakpoints in these event handlers and ensure they are getting hit properly.

For two, `StorageArea.set(object items, function callback)` is the signature of the set method.  To set two values, you want to pass a single object instead of two different objects:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({
    'Name': newname,
    'Email': newemail
  }, function() {
    // Check chrome.runtime.lastError to see if there was an error
    ...
  });
```

Lastly, there's no real reason to use `window.onload` (I think you meant to use `window.onload` here, right?) or two different `DOMContentLoaded` listeners; why not consolidate them into one (not forgetting to check for `getElementById` returning null, since it seems like you're sharing this script between the two pages)?

Edit: also, you appear to be mixing sync/local storage for your set/get respectively.

Comment: hey thank you for the great explanation! This is my first piece of javascript code ever, so it is a little messy, I added the `myJs` stuff only because I was getting errors about my second `DOMContentLoaded`. I will go ahead and remake the code based on your suggestions and possibly return here if I fail miserably =)

Comment: @SamFisher: did you end up figuring out the issue?

Comment: yep, I have, still need to put a few final touches before I post it as a reply here, just haven't had the time =)